# Dividir Campo Email de 1 textbox y mostrar en un combobox

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net

Estoy intentando de crear una función para  dividir el campo **EMAIL** mostrado en un textbox a partir del "@" y mostrarlo en un combo-box en Visual Studios 2010, el dato email es extraido de la base de datos sql server 2018.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando que se muestre de la siguiente manera,bien por Visual studio con una funcion o por SQLServer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estableci esta funcion para separar el correo del textbox pero algo me esta faltando porque aun se queda establecido el **@outlook.com** en la caja de texto adjunto el codigo:

```
 Sub obtenerdominio()
    Dim dominio As String() = Me.txtCorreo.Text.Split("@")
    Me.cbodominio.Text = dominio(1)

End Sub
```

y me esta quedando asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
por favor su apoyo muchas gracias.

Comment: Como conseguiste Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo estas haciendo casi bien...

Esto:

```
Me.txtCorreo.Text.Split("@")
```

Divide la cadena en un array de strings, divididos por el string que pedis...

Pero, no divide la cadena que estas pasando, si no que genera un array de nuevas cadenas.

Asi que si vos queres que en txtCorreo quede lo que se dividio, se lo tenes que pasar de vuelta:

```
Sub obtenerdominio()
    Dim dominio As String() = Me.txtCorreo.Text.Split("@")
    Me.txtCorreo.Text = dominio(0)
    Me.cbodominio.Text = dominio(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Esta bien hace la división del campo correo,pero en este lo esta pasando sin el "@",como haria para pasar de la siguiente manera @OUTLOOK.COM ?

Comment: bueno, vos pediste dividir por @.. y como es la cadena por la que divide, la saca.. agregala a mano y listo...

Answer (score 0):

Agregue un plus adiccional a la ayuda de gbianchi,en la base de datos ejecute esto en el procedimiento almacenado

```
SELECT E_MAIL,SUBSTRING(E_MAIL, CHARINDEX('@', E_MAIL), LEN(E_MAIL)) AS Dominio from clientes
```

de ahi en VB ejecute la funcion indicada lineas arriba en este caso solo a la caja de texto email le aplique la funcion SPLIT